# Add my own message type information in Smack Object Message

Tags: android, xmpp, message, smack

I am using Smack 4.1.3 and Openfire. In my design, when a user wants to send a photo or video file to another user. My application will not do XMPP file transfer. Instead, the App will upload the photo or video to a web server and then send this URL as Message body. The App of the target user will check the file type of the file, then download and process it according to it's file type. So instead of simply sending the URL, I want to include the file type in Message body as well.

The questions are

1) What is the best way to add such information in the Message body?
2) I was thinking to add some tags in the Message body as below. Is there any concern? (especially when it is converted to XMPP xml file during transfer)

```
    <myFileType>photo</myFileType><myBody>http://myserver.com/image.png</myBody>
```

3) Do I need to add any prefix/namespace information of my tags above?

Sending message

```
    String to = "abc@myserver.com";
    String text = ........;   //want to add file type information and the URL here
    Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
    msg.setBody(text);
    connectionsManager.sendStanza(msg);
```

Receiving message

```
connection.addAsyncStanzaListener(new StanzaListener() {
    @Override
    public void processPacket(Stanza packet) {
        Message message = (Message) packet;
        if (message.getBody() != null) {
            String fromName = message.getFrom();
            String body = message.getBody());
            // want to extract myFileType and myBody from String body
```

Comment: The usual way would be to create a custom ExtensionElement for your custom data.

Comment: make changes in Message class of asmack

in Message class toXML() method change this method add your own tag